# Continuity/differentiability at a point and in some neighbourhood of the point

Tags: real-analysis

For a function $f: U \to \mathbb{R}$ where $U$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}$, it seems like that it being continuous at a point doesn't imply that there is a neighbourhood of the point where it can be continuous. Similarly, it seems like that it being differentiable at a point doesn't imply that there is a neighbourhood of the point where it can be differentiable. I was wondering if there are some counterexamples to confirm the above?

**Added:**

What are some necessary and/or sufficient conditions for continuity/differentiability at a point and in some neighbourhood of the point to be equivalent?

Can the case of continuity be generalized to mappings between topological spaces?

Thanks and regards!

Comment: What is $U$? A topological space, or just a metric space?

Comment: $U$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/22839

Comment: Hmm, I hadn't notice that the linked question was asked by the same person.  Tim, did you realize you had already asked this question?

Comment: @JonasMeyer: I didn't. I didn't see your last comment link to my old question either. But I do now.

Answer (score 5):

Define $f$ by putting $f(x) = 1$ if $x$ is rational and $f(x) = 0$ if $x$ is irrational. Let $g(x) = x \cdot f(x)$ and let $h(x) = x^2 \cdot f(x).$

$g$ is continuous at $x=0$ and $g$ is not continuous at each $x \neq 0.$

$h$ is differentiable at $x=0$ and $h$ is not differentiable at each $x \neq 0.$

(In fact, $g$ is also not differentiable at $x=0$ and $h$ is not continuous at each $x \neq 0$.)

Comment: +1. Thanks! Do you know what are some necessary and/or sufficient conditions for continuity/differentiability at a point and in some neighbourhood of the point to be equivalent?

Answer (score 3):

Any function $f$ on $[-1,1]$ with $|f(x)| \le x^2$ is differentiable at $0$.  You could e.g. take $f(x) = x^2$ when $x$ is rational and $-x^2$ when $x$ is irrational.

Comment: +1. Thanks! I wonder what are some necessary and/or sufficient conditions for continuity/differentiability at a point and in some neighbourhood of the point to be equivalent?