# Is there a function $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ that has only one point differentiable?

Tags: calculus

While studying complex variables, I could learn that $f(z)=|z|^{2}$ has only one point which is $z=0$ that $f$ being differentiable and $f$ being not differentiable at any other points.

Then, I was wondering if there is a function $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ that has only one point differentiable and not on any other points.

In intuition, it seems there are no such point!
However, I have no idea how I can prove this...

Additional question is that would there be any function $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ that has only one point continuous and not on any other points.

I think this is pretty interesting things to think about! :-)

Comment: [Here's a thread](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/108388) on continuous functions differentiable only at one point.

Comment: Note that André's example below is a function that is only continuous at one point and is only differentiable at one point.

Comment: If you like such questions, you might want to check out the books by [Bruckner, Bruckner and Thompson](http://classicalrealanalysis.info/index.php) and pick the one that suits your level (the texts are available electronically for free).

Comment: Thank you for all your comments! Now I know that the above property of complex functions is not a special thing that is different from real functions.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Let $$p(x)= \begin{cases} 0,& x\in\mathbb Q\\\\1,& x\in \mathbb R-\mathbb Q \end{cases}$$ Now take $f(x)=x^2p(x)$.

Comment: Thank you! this gives me a perfect answer that I can be convinced!

Comment: @Emily: Regarding to $f(x)$ above, if you want a function differentiable at 2 points you can take $(x-1)^2f(x)$. It is differentiable at x=0 and x=1 only.

Comment: @Emily Another possible generalization: if you take $f(x) = x^np(x)$, with $p(x)$ as above, then $f$ is $(n-1)$ times differentiable at $0$, and not differentiable anywhere else. To make sense of that, you have to write a single limit corresponding to the $n$th derivative at $0$ (since you can't compute limits using $f'$, because $f'$ only exists at $0$).

Comment: Ah, but can you write a continuous function which is only differentiable in one point?

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Yes, but need to quote a non-trivial result, that there is a bounded continuous nowhere differentiable function. Then the $x^2$ trick fixes things at $0$, and doesn't help at $x\ne 0$.

Comment: @student what exactly "a single limit corresponding to the $n$th derivative at $0$" is supposed to mean?

Comment: @AsafKaragila But what does differentiability only at a single point mean? To me, the concept of differentiability seems to give an idea of local behaviour on a neighbourhood.

Comment: @Jamāl: Well, let me ask you this in the other way, what does it mean that $f(x)=|x|$ is differentiable in all but one point?

Comment: @AsafKaragila In this case it would mean that the behaviour on a neighborhood about $0$ is different on its left and right side. Specifically, the tangent line changes suddenly as we move it about $0$.

Comment: @Jamāl: Well, being differentiable at a single point is the same. It means that the rate of change around the point has a limit as we get closer to the point.

Comment: @AsafKaragila hmm. That actually makes sense. I would imagine that the tangent line undergoes infinitely many bumps as it approaches the differentiable point from either side but the value of the tangent we get is the same from either side. Thanks for clearing up my intuition.