# Give an example of a function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ which is continuous only at $0$.

Tags: real-analysis, functions

I do not know an example. Will ask question if in doubt of the proofs provided thank you!!

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/194194

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$
F(x) = \left\{
\begin{array}{rcl}
x,& \mbox{if} & x \in \mathbb{Q}\\
-x , & \mbox{if} & x \notin \mathbb{Q} \\
\end{array}
\right.
$$

$|x-0| < \varepsilon \Rightarrow |f(x) - f(0)| = |x| <\varepsilon$. If $x_0 > 0$. There is $x \notin \mathbb{Q}$ sufficiently  near $x_0$  such that $f(x) = -x$ is sufficiently  near $-x_0$. Thus do not sufficiently  near $f(x_0) = x_0$.

Comment: how would I show for only continous except at the integers?

Comment: Do you mean continuous except at the integers or discontinuous except at the integers?

Comment: an example where f:R--->R which is continuous except at the integers.

Comment: That's much easier really... the indicator function for Z should do the trick.

Answer (score 13):

Let $g(x)=1$ if $x$ is rational, and $0$ if $x$ is irrational. Let $f(x)=xg(x)$.

Answer (score 3):

$$
f(x) = \left\{ \begin{array}{rl}
 x^{2} &\mbox{ if $x$ is rational} \\
  -x^{2} &\mbox{ otherwise}
       \end{array} \right.
$$