# why here $x^2$ is used ? why not $x ?$

Tags: real-analysis

> Does  there exists a function $f : \mathbb{R }\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ which is differentiable only at the point $0.$?

My attempt :  I found the  answer  here [Is there a function $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ that has only one point differentiable?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/194194/is-there-a-function-f-mathbb-r-to-mathbb-r-that-has-only-one-point-differe)

But  i didn't understands the  answer , my doubts given below

[image]

Comment: The proof that $f$  is differentiable at the origin doesn't work with $x$ in place of $x^2$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich   im asking the  reason why ? i mean  $0^2 = 0$ , $0$ is  idempotent

Comment: The reason why is exactly what I said. If we said $f(x)=xp(x)$ then $f$ would not be differentiable.

Comment: More specifically, with $f(x)=xp(x), $ the derivative would be  $\lim\limits_{x\to0} xp(x)/x$, which does not exist because $p(x) $ takes values of $0$ and $1$ for arbitrarily small $x$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because while $x p(x)$ is continuous at $0$, it is not differentiable.

In particular, the fraction
$$
\frac{(0+h)p(0+h)-0p(0)}{h}
$$
has value $0$ or $1$ depending on whether $h$ is rational or not. So it has no limit as $h\to 0$, which by definition of derivative means that $xp(x)$ had no derivative at $0$.

On the other hand, the fraction
$$
\frac{(0+h)^2p(0+h)-0^2p(0)}{h}
$$
has value $h$ or $0$ depending on whether $h$ is rational or irrational. Thus it *does* have a limit as $h\to0$, which is to say that $x^2p(x)$ has derivative $0$ at $x=0$.

Answer (score 1):

The function with $x$ is not differentiable at $0$. For instance in the limit defining the derivative, the $\lim \sup$ exists and is $1$, and the $\lim \inf$ exists and is $0.$ These are not equal, so the derivative doesn't exist at $0.$

Answer (score 1):

Note that $f(0)=0$ and $\frac{f(x)}{x}=xp(x)$

And the limit of $xp(x)$ at zero is zero.

If $f=xp(x)$ then $\frac{f(x)}{x}=p(x)$

and the limit of $p(x)$ at zero does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

With $f(x)=xp(x),$ the derivative at $0$ would be $\lim\limits_{x\to0}\dfrac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}=\lim\limits_{x\to0}\dfrac{xp(x)}x=\lim\limits_{x\to0}p(x),$

which does not exist, since $p(x)$ takes values of $0$ and $1$ for arbitrarily small $x$.