# Function Only Differentiable at Point but with Non-Zero Derivative

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, continuity

**Does there exist a function $f:\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R}$ that is only differentiable at $x=0$ with $f'(0)\neq0$ ?**

This is a straightforward question to ask, but I'm having difficulty proving it rigorously.

I know that it is possible for functions to be differentiable only at a single point (see  [Is there a function $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ that has only one point differentiable?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/194194/is-there-a-function-f-mathbb-r-to-mathbb-r-that-has-only-one-point-differe?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [Function which is continuous everywhere in its domain, but differentiable only at one point](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/108388/function-which-is-continuous-everywhere-in-its-domain-but-differentiable-only-a)). Moreover, I know of at least one function that is differentiable only at $x=0$ with the derivative there being  $0$  (see https://planetmath.org/functiondifferentiableatonlyonepoint for the example).

My question is: can you have a function that is differentiable only at a point with the derivative there being ***non-zero***? Intuitively, the answer seems to be "NO" given that a non-zero derivative at a point implies that the function is "changing" (in a somewhat vague sense) about that point, which in turn suggests that there's a small neighborhood around the point where other derivatives would exist. Seeing that the function is only differentiable at one point, this would be a clear contradiction.

I don't know if this intuition is correct let alone how I could use it to answer the question. How should one approach proving this? Should you invoke the linearity of the function around the differentiable point? That was another idea I had.

Comment: If $f$ is differentiable only at $x=0$ with $f'(0) = 0$ then $g(x) = f(x)+x$ is differentiable only at $x=0$ with $g'(0)=1$.

Comment: Good example. Thank you for that. I'm not sure where my brain was but I clearly over-thought this question.