# Locally differentiable implies locally Lipschitz for multivariable functions

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, lipschitz-functions

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^{n}\to \mathbb{R}^{n}$ s.t. $f$ is differentiable at $\underline{x}$ with $D_{\underline{x}}f=I$ and $f(\underline{x})= \underline{0}$.
I want to prove that there exists $r>0$  and $C>0$ s.t.
$$
\|f(x_{1})-f(x_{2})\|\leq C \|x_{1}-x_{2}\| \quad \forall x_{1},x_{2}\in B(\underline{x},r)
$$
With differentiable I mean the following
$$
\begin{align}
&\lim_{ \|x-\underline{x}\| \to 0 } \frac{\|f(x)-f(\underline{x})-D_{\underline{x}}f(x-\underline{x})\|}{\|x-\underline{x}\|} \\
=&\lim_{ \|x-\underline{x}\| \to 0 } \frac{\|f(x)-(x-\underline{x})\|}{\|x-\underline{x}\|}=0
\end{align}
$$

I don't have the differentiability in other points, in that case I found a proof [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/73426/603403)

From the definition of differentiable follows that for any $\epsilon>0$ holds
$$
\|f(x)-(x-\underline{x})\| \leq \epsilon\|x-\underline{x}\|
$$
From there, using the triangular inequality, follows
$$
\begin{align}
\|f(x_{1})-f(x_{2})\|&=\|f(x_{1})-(x_{1}-\underline{x})+(x_{1}-x_{2})-f(x_{2})-(x_{2}-\underline{x})\| \\
&\geq \|f(x_{1})-(x_{1}-\underline{x})\|+\|x_{1}-x_{2}\|+\|f(x_{2})-(x_{2}-\underline{x})\| \\
&\geq\epsilon(\|x_{1}-\underline{x}\|+\|x_{2}-\underline{x}\|) + \|x_{1}-x_{2}\|
\end{align}
$$
which it doesn't help me so much.

Comment: So what have you tried? There are some standard things you should be writing down. Where do you get stuck? Edit your question to include these.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, I updated the question as you asked

Comment: Try direct triangle inequality? Consider $\|f(x_1)-f(x_2)-(x_1-x_2)\|$, perhaps?

Comment: I don't see the how to use your hint

Comment: If I try to use your suggestion I get $\|f(x_1)-f(x_2)\| \leq \epsilon(\|\underline{x}-x_1\|+\|\underline{x}-x_2\|)$ which is similar to the result I wrote in the question.

Comment: Did you try to find a counter example for functions of one variable? (A function differentiable at one point and discontinuous elsewhere.)

Comment: [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/108392/603403) they give an example of such a function. So it's not true because lipschitz in an open set implies continuity in the same set. How can I mark as solved?

Comment: You can either delete or post your own answer and accept it.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/108388/function-which-is-continuous-everywhere-in-its-domain-but-differentiable-only-a/108392#108392)  is given an example of a function differentiable in one point and discontinuous everywhere else. In particular, since Lipschitz implies continuity, it isn't true that a function differentiable in one point then it's continuous in its neighbourhood.